# Call other batch files and handle the closing

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, exit

I want to call two batch files which are executed at the same time. This is how it currently looks:

*backup.bat*

```
start backup1.bat
start backup2.bat
pause
```

*backup1.bat*

```
Title Backup1
call do_backup.bat "param1" "param2"
exit
```

*backup2.bat*

```
Title Backup2
call do_backup.bat "param3" "param4"
exit
```

*do_backup.bat*

```
REM robocopy is called and some other things are done here
exit
```

If I do this two windows are opened, but *backup1.bat* und *backup2.bat* are not closed (and also not exited?). The show their output, but the user can't enter new commands. Only with Strg + C he can abort the batch files, despite they have finished ...

I want that *backup.bat* opens *backup1.bat* and *backup2.bat* and they should be processed simultaneously. Is opening in a new window the correct way? In this case the *backup1.bat* and *backup2.bat* windows should close when finished. It would be interesting to see the outputs in *backup.bat* and it should finish here with "Please press any key" if this is possible.

So how can I handle the closing/exiting here?

Comment: The CALL command waits for the program it executed to finish before moving on to the next command.

Comment: So what does that mean? `Robocopy` has finished, I see that in the log files.

Comment: I can only guess because you are not showing us all the code in the last batch file.

Comment: OK, I'll update the question with the full code.

Comment: `start` runs batchfiles with cmd /k so windows stay open. Try starting the batchfiles `cmd /c batchfile.bat`.

Comment: @bgalea: I tried that. Now it hangs at the first batch file. With Strg + C the next batch file is processed ...

Comment: I meant using `Start` with `cmd /c` ie `start "" cmd /c batchfile.bat`. See `start /?` for the ins and outs of starting programs with or without `start`. Try not using `exit` at all or try `exit /b`. See `exit /?`.

Comment: @bgalea: Now I tried that. The new windows are opened and closed correctly. Is there a way to route the output to the main window? Perhaps you want post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Only by using a temporary file. `...etc batchfile.bat > "%temp%\MyTempFile.txt"` to write it (although it might work better if in the batchfile - `command >> TempFile.txt`. To display `type "%temp%\MyTempFile.txt"`. Have you thought about how you will answer your own question?

Comment: Read the help for the START command. I bet you will find your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to bgalea again. This is what I have now and perhaps modify later:

*backup.bat*

```
start "" cmd /c backup1.bat
start "" cmd /c backup2.bat
pause
```

*backup1.bat*

```
Title Backup1
call do_backup.bat "param1" "param2"
exit /b
```

*backup2.bat*

```
Title Backup2
call do_backup.bat "param3" "param4"
exit /b
```

*do_backup.bat*

```
REM robocopy is called and some other things are done here
exit /b
```

Seems to do that what I wanted. Now two windows are opened and they are also closed when finished.